# eventListener on button to exchange data between HTML client and node.js server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to pass a json object between a server and client. The server-side this far looks like:

```
var express = require('express'); // Express web server framework
var request = require('request'); // "Request" library
var querystring = require('querystring');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");


var app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.post("/", function (req, res) {

    console.log('Request received');
    var return_value;

    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('GOT DATA!');
        json = JSON.parse(chunk);
        json.access_date  =  "12.04.17";
        return_value = JSON.stringify(chunk);
    });

    res.writeHead(200, { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' 
    });
    res.json(return_value);

})


var server = app.listen("8080")
console.log('Server running port 8080/');
```

With the following function attached to a button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", passArg);

function passArg() {
    console.log("I'm here")
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "/", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
           if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                //var json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                console.log("Data passed back: " + xmlhttp.responseText)
           }
           else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
              alert('There was an error 400');
           }
           else {
               alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
           }
        }
    }

    var data = JSON.stringify({"email":"hey@mail.com","password":"101010"});
    xmlhttp.send(data);
}
</script>
```

Now upon clicking the console log "I'm here" triggers fine, but the function returns a 404 error on the POST part of the code. I also don't entirely understand how to pass data back to the client from the server. Would the method `res.end()` be the correct way?

EDIT: I've edited the scripts to reflect the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 changes I see need to be made

**1**

As @charietfl mentioned, you can probably simplify your `xmlhttp.open()` call by just including the path to your `express` endpoint.

You currently aren't calling your `/callback` endpoint, so I would put that in your `xhtmlhttp.open()` call.

Something like `xmlhttp.open('POST', '/callback')`

**2**

As @Bshaps mentioned, you also have an endpoint that is expecting a `GET` request, but you are using `POST` so changing

```
app.get("/callback"...
```

to

```
app.post("/callback"...
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked brilliantly. I'm still stuck on how to send an object back to the client, however. If you could shed some light on that I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your server is receiving a post request, but your route is for a get request.

Change:

```
app.get("/callback", function(req, res){
```

To:

```
app.post("/callback", function(req, res){
```

Answer (score 0):

inspect actual request in browser dev tools network. Will likely see request is to `'http://localhost:8080/localhost:8080` ... add protocol to the url used

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080")
```

Or just set it as:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "/")
```

And add a `post` route server side